# Meaning of the aptitude search output for wine-staging

Tags: wine, aptitude

I've installed `winehq-staging` package from [winehq repo](https://wiki.winehq.org/Debian) in debian 12 instead of from debian repo which I'll be using from Lutris.

After that I listed what got installed with:

```
aptitude search '?narrow(?installed,?origin(dl.winehq.org))'
```

And this command printed out:

```
i A wine-staging                                   - WINE Is Not An Emulator - runs MS Windows programs       
i A wine-staging-amd64                             - WINE Is Not An Emulator - runs MS Windows programs       
i A wine-staging-i386:i386                         - WINE Is Not An Emulator - runs MS Windows programs       
i   winehq-staging                                 - WINE Is Not An Emulator - runs MS Windows programs
```

I'm having trouble understanding this output:

1. What does the letter "A" mean in the output?
2. What's the difference between `winehq-staging` and `wine-staging`
3. Since there are x64 and x86 bit versions installed what do the other two mean? that is what exactly do 4 of these version mean and how are they used?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. The “A” in the output means that the package was installed automatically (pulled in by another package). Essentially, if you removing `winehq-staging`, the other three packages will be removed too (immediately with `aptitude`, or the next time you run `apt autoremove`).
2. `wine-staging` provides the WineHQ staging version of Wine; `winehq-staging` uses that to provide the main version of Wine, system-wide. (See the package descriptions.)
3. `winehq-staging` depends on `wine-staging`, which depends on `wine-staging-amd64` and `wine-staging-i386`. `wine-staging-amd64` provides 64-bit Windows support, `wine-staging-i386` provides 32-bit Windows support, `wine-staging` is a meta-package pulling in both of those.

In most cases `winehq-staging` (or the equivalent from another branch) is the appropriate package to install. Having split packages allows more complex setups with multiple versions installed in parallel. See [the Wine wiki](https://wiki.winehq.org/Debian#Notes) for details.